# I don't get a code error when uploading an image file, I get the required error that I set myself, where am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

when I want to save an image, I encounter a problem, the error I forced in the model comes, but I do not get any error line while the application is running, when I go with break points, I see that the image comes up to the model valid, but the valid returns false, but I could not find the solution, can you please help?

The field where I get image data on my Create page

```
<div class="form-group my-3">
    <label asp-for="UniversityImage"></label>
    <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

my admin dashboard

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] UniversityDtoForInsertion universityDto, IFormFile file)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images", file.FileName);

         await using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
         {
             await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
         }
         universityDto.UniversityImage = String.Concat("/images/", file.FileName);
         _serviceManager.UniversityService.CreateUniversity(universityDto);
         TempData["success"] = $"{universityDto.UniversityName} has been created.";
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View();

 }
```

data transfer object

```
public record UniversityDto
{
    public int UniversityId { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UniversityName is Required")]
    public string UniversityName { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UniversityDescription is Required")]
    public string UniversityDescription { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UniversityAddress is Required")]
    public string UniversityAddress { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UniversityWebAddress is Required")]
    public string UniversityWebAddress { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UniversityPhone is Required")]
    public string UniversityPhone { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UniversityImage is Required")]
    public string UniversityImage { get; set; }

}
```

IUniversityService  layer

`University CreateUniversity(UniversityDtoForInsertion universityDto);`

UniversityManager layer

```
 public University CreateUniversity(UniversityDtoForInsertion universityDto)
 {
     if (universityDto is null)
     {
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(universityDto));
     }

     University university = _mapper.Map<University>(universityDto);

     _manager.University.Create(university);
     _manager.Save();
     return university;
 }
```

IUniversityRepository layer

```
 public interface IUniversityRepository : IRepositoryBase<University>
 {
     IQueryable<University> GetAllUniversities(bool trackChanges);
     University? GetOneUniversity(int id, bool trackChanges);

     void CreateOneUni(University university);
     void UpdateOneUni(University university);
     void DeleteOneUni(University university);
 }
```

UniversityRepository Layer

```
 public void CreateOneUni(University university) => Create(university);
```

When I move forward with Breakpoints, the point where it shows the problem is available in the image below, can you please help?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label asp-for="UniversityImage"></label>
<input name="file" type="file" class="form-control" />
```

You bind the input UniversityImage to `file`  , so the UniversityImage is null, then you get the required error .
Since you  add UniversityImage by

> universityDto.UniversityImage = String.Concat("/images/",
> file.FileName);

you can try the below two ways.

Try to add it before checking ModelState.IsValid like:

```
 universityDto.UniversityImage = String.Concat("/images/", file.FileName);
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {...}
```

**OR**

remove UniversityImage error

```
ModelState.Remove("UniversityImage");
if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {...}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the second way worked